# CSS drop-down menu issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm working on this template: http://ayb-sd.org/ayb2/, and I've a slight problem with positioning the navigation menu. When I hover over item 'Franchises' it drops down 'Projects' item but with inside navigation container.

I tried increasing the height but ended up increasing the whole menu's height. Now I need the menu drop-downed items to be on top of bottom image slider.

Thanks

Comment: Please show us important parts of you HTML/CSS in order to help you

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `overflow: hidden` in `.widget`:

```
.widget {
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #FFF;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #eee9d8;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #EEE9D8;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #EEE9D8;
   margin-top: 13px;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
}
.navigation2 .widget {
   overflow: visible;
}
```

P.S. Next time, please, provide us with your code and what you tried.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried removing it and it worked, but got the widgets on right bar removed!

Comment: still removing overflow: hidden removes right side widgets

Comment: @user3734829, right. You should return `overflow: hidden` for '.widget'

Comment: I fixed it. Added "overflow: visible;" to ".navigation2 .widget". Thanks a lot :)